# Not able to figure out why bootstrap close is not workign

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I was messing around the django and bootstarp ! and have this piece of code in my html file.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
   Error: 1.2.3.4 - This IP address already exists !! and is added by &quot;bana&quot;
</div>
```

but the close button is not able to close the alert message.  I have attached the whole html file please take a look.

http://shrib.com/XWmnns8a

Answer (score 0):

It was missing jquery ! so just added

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

this and it works well!